# int.Parse Value cannot be null for non-null string

Tags: c#

Despite checking whether input string is not null or empty, I'm getting `Value cannot be null` exception when parsing that string to integer. I haven't debugged it yet for the actual value that is being passed to the function because I already have `if not string null or empty` before I try the parse.

```
int groupCredits = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(course.Credits))
    groupCredits += int.Parse(course.Credits);
```

**Exception:**

`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)`

Comment: Do you have multiple threads changing Credits value? If not then check if you are using latest version of assembly, which has String.IsNullOrEmpty check

Comment: What is the actual value of course.Credits before the comparison and after comparison? Have you debugged it(Debug.Write(course.Credits) or manually)?

Comment: Can you show an example of groupCredits value ?

Comment: Are you sure that is the line causing the exception?  Maybe you are trying to parse it a few lines down.

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?  What platform?  Which toolchain?

Comment: minimal failing example is needed

Comment: this is a .net 4.5 MVC4 web API; currently waiting on live debug message to be captured and will post as soon as i see it (or will post the resolution - whatever i overlooked).